# SSIS Web Service Task Pulls Connection String From WSDL?

Tags: c#, web-services, ssis

I have a simple SSIS package. In it there is a `Web Service Task`. That web service task uses an `HTTP Connection Manager` for its connection, naturally.

I have used Expressions to set the `ConnectionString` and `ServerURL` to use parameters defined on the package, with the goal of being able to change the connection string after the package is deployed. I want to do this so that I can deploy the package to different test environments and have it consume an appropriate web service in the matching environment.

The expressions seem to work for the `HTTP Connection Manager`. I can change the value of my parameters, and (after saving, closing, and re-openeing the package) the values of the connection manager match the package parameters. However, the problem I am having is that when I run the package, it still consumes the old service url until I re-download the WSDL. I've opened the WSDL and it clearly contains the url of the service it was downloaded from.

How can I make my package consume the service url set in the package parameter and applied to the connection manager instead of the one contained in the WSDL? Must I really re-download the WSDL for each environment? If yes, what is the point of having configurable connections on the `HTTP Connection Manager`?